# Redux Reducers vs BLoC MapEventToState

Tags: react-native, flutter, redux, bloc

I've always seen Redux Reducers very similar to the mapEventToState function of BLoC State Management. However now I notice a big difference between the two patterns and it is that the Reducers must be "pure functions" while the function mapEventToState (in many examples) can even make http request.

At this point I wonder if it is actually possible to manage mapEventToState as "pure function" adding maybe another layer of abstraction.

Answer (score 2):

As I see, `mapEventToState` from Bloc is a merge of Reducer and Middleware layers from Redux.

In Redux, actions can be intercepted by middlewares that creates new actions (side effects) parsed by reducers. IMHO this is one of the reasons Bloc is less cumbersome and more readable than Redux.

A good idea is to extract the data layer and inject the implementation on your bloc, receiving results as futures and yielding the new states.